# UWP - zooming image (with pinch zoom and double tap), with Flip View

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp, flipview

I need to show images (using Flip View controll) and allow users to zoom them (with pinch zoom and with double tap) and drag zoomed image.

I would like it to be compatible with Flip View (I mean it shouldn't ovveride draging gesture).

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need to show images (using Flip View controll) and allow users to zoom them (with pinch zoom and with double tap) and drag zoomed image.

We can use the [`ScrollViewer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) control and [`UIElement.DoubleTapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.doubletapped.aspx) event to allow users to zoom the images (with pinch zoom and with double tap) and drag zoomed image.

In order to zoom the image with pinch zoom and drag zoomed image. We can put the [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx) into the `ScrollViewer`.

We can add `UIElement.DoubleTapped` event in the `ScrollViewer` to zoom the image with double tap.

For example:

In XAML:

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <FlipView Name="MyFlipView">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyImage">
                    <ScrollViewer  MinZoomFactor="1" DoubleTapped="scrollViewer_DoubleTapped"
                  ZoomMode="Enabled">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
    </Grid>
```

In code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyImage> MyImages;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyImages = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>();
    MyImages.Add(new MyImage("ms-appx:///Assets/cliff.jpg"));
    MyImages.Add(new MyImage("ms-appx:///Assets/grapes.jpg"));
    MyImages.Add(new MyImage("ms-appx:///Assets/rainer.jpg"));
    MyImages.Add(new MyImage("ms-appx:///Assets/sunset.jpg"));
    MyImages.Add(new MyImage("ms-appx:///Assets/valley.jpg"));
    MyFlipView.ItemsSource = MyImages;
}

private async void scrollViewer_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    var doubleTapPoint = e.GetPosition(scrollViewer);

    if (scrollViewer.ZoomFactor != 1)
    {
        scrollViewer.ZoomToFactor(1);
    }
    else if (scrollViewer.ZoomFactor == 1)
    {
        scrollViewer.ZoomToFactor(2);

        var dispatcher = Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
      {
          scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(doubleTapPoint.X);
          scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(doubleTapPoint.Y);
      });
    }
}
```

And the MyImage Class code:

```
public class MyImage
{
    public MyImage()
    {
    }

    public MyImage(string uri)
    {
        this.Path = uri;
    }

    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it caused an issue. When I go to the gallery, my images are zoomed already (like Stretch="Uniform" didn't work). How can I fix it?

Comment: Please remove the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` of the `ScrollViewer`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I also needed to put Image inside of <Grid> control to center it, but now it works! :)