# Xamarin Forms: How to zoom in and zoom out image on button click in UWP?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

In my application, I have an image control with a scrollbar. so I want to zoom in and zoom out the image on (Plus, Minus) button click.

```
 <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewerimage" 

          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 

          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="42,10,19,259" Grid.Row="2" ViewChanged="ScrollViewerimage_ViewChanged" SizeChanged="ScrollViewerimage_SizeChanged">
        <Image       x:Name="DisplayImage"   Stretch="None"
              Margin="0,0,0,0"   Width="647"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Height="585" Grid.Row="1" >

        </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: guys any idea how to zoom in and zoom out on button click. :(

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply . i am developing desktop UWP application :(

Comment: Here is link for refernce.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380661/uwp-zooming-image-with-pinch-zoom-and-double-tap-with-flip-view)